# Complex Query in Mongodb using driver (subtraction of dates and mod)

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-.net-driver

I want to write a Query like this:

```
Builders<Test>.Filter.Mod(s=> (s.StartDateTime - requiredDate).Days, s.frequence, 0)
```

***this is not working.***

Also a query like this:

```
s => DateTime.DaysInMonth(s.StartDateTime.Year, s.StartDateTime.Month) - s.LastDays < requiredDate.Day
```

***This is not working too.***

Both are giving me "Not supported" error.

Is there any equivalent way of querying such thing?

Comment: could you please be _more precise_ about what exactly "is not working" means? what is supposed to happen, and what is happening instead? i recommend [taking the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), as well as reading [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [what's on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: They are giving me errors, "Not supported" error.